# Базовая сборка System.dll от Silverlight в проекте WinForms\WPF, возможно?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight

Есть проект на WinForms или WPF.

Мне нужно использовать в этом проекте тип WriteableBitmap из сборки System.dll от Silverlight. Но у проекта WinForms\WPF уже есть своя базовая сборка System.

Есть ли какой либо разумный выход из ситуации?

*p.s. использовать WriteableBitmap из WinForms\WPF или сторонние реализации - не предлагать, ибо очень много работы получится.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это невозможно.

Код абсолютно несовместим, потому что это разные платформы и разный рантайм. По сути, даже интероп нормально не проработан: [интеропа на уровне управляемого кода нет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4934935). И никогда не будет, потому что сервелат — умирающая технология.

Всё, что вы можете сделать — это положить на формочку WPF/WinForms контрол браузера и открыть в нём приложение сервелата. Взаимодействовать можно через жабоскрипт и DOM. Или через COM. Другого интеропа нет.